# PyMongo how to get the last item in the collection?

Tags: python, pymongo

In the MongoDB console, I know that you can use $ last and $ natural. In PyMongo, I could not use it, maybe I was doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you considered the case of the $ is not valid in Python? They must have equivalents implemented. Please look harder before asking question.

Comment: what was the query you tried to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last item using [find_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) function.

```
last_doc = db.docs.find_one(
  {'doc_id': doc_id},
  sort=[( '_id', pymongo.DESCENDING )]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:
`db.collection.find().limit(1).sort([('$natural',-1)])`

This seemed to work best for me.